# Can't connect to Compose.io with MongoChef

Tags: mongodb, compose-db, studio3t

I try to connect to a replica set, I defined a user in the admin database and I enabled SSL. But no matter what I try I just get a failed connection.

I followed this, but still nothing:
https://thomaszahn.wordpress.com/2014/10/20/connecting-to-a-hosted-mongodb-database-using-3t-mongochef/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB URI strings with multiple servers will be imported as connections to a MongoDB replica set. Please verify that your MongoDB instances are members of a replica set and not members of a sharded cluster. When connecting to a sharded cluster use **Sharded Cluster** as the connection type.

MongoChef 3.4.0 and newer will perform this check for you automatically.